# Unexpected compiler error (Superfluous Cast?)

Tags: casting, g++

I'm currently in the process of writing my own kernel bottom up, and I've come across this little issue in my linear memory manager, that I can't seem to understand.

I've got the following piece of code;

`void* end_page_address = /*(void*)*/ 0x3FF000;`

However, when the void pointer cast is disabled, I get the following error by g++;

`src/paging/LinearMemoryManager.cpp: In constructor 'LinearMemoryManager::LinearMemoryManager(PhysicalMemoryManager*)':
src/paging/LinearMemoryManager.cpp:87:42: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'void*' [-fpermissive]`

How come? - Because it's apparently not generally needed, as the line just above it compiles just fine without a cast:

`void* start_page_address = 0x00000000;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the NULL pointer, which has address 0, (even written as `0x00000` or similar), deserves a specific treatment in the C++ specification (and inside the GCC compiler). BTW, C++11 added `nullptr` and its type with good reasons.

But non-zero addresses like `void* end_page_address = (void*) 0x3FF000;`  need an explicit cast.

I hope you are aware of C++ tricks (exceptions, constructors, RTTI, ...) when coding a kernel with it. You might need to understand *exactly* how your particular version of `g++` handles them.

<sup>I also hope your kernel is free software (GPL-ed), and that you follow the *"release early, release often"* motto. I'll be curious to look inside its source code.</sup>

Comment: Hi Basile. You might be right, that it's due to special treatment of the null ptr, I didn't really consider that since it's just another address in the paging system (namely where the first page_frame starts). - And I do know about the nullptr in C++11 and I am using it elsewhere, but I think it would be wrong to use it in the case, where I actually want the address 0x0, not a null pointer.

Comment: As for the C++ tricks, I don't really understand which tricks you're refering to, but in order to support exceptions I'll need to port the unwinding library first, and in order to support RTTI I'll need to port the C++ runtime, as for constructors, which tricks are you thinking about? - Also my kernel is currently not licensed in any way, but it will be free software (don't worry), and if you want me to, I can contact you when I'm out of Alpha state and pushing it to a public repository?

Comment: AFAIK, the GCC compiler has quite deeply (for common targets like x86 or x86-64 or ARM or PowerPC, Sparc, etc...) the assomption that 0 is the null pointer and should never be dereferenced. So don't use that address, even inside your kernel, even if it is mapped ....

Comment: I'm not dereferencing it, I'm just using it to define the start of the very first pageframe.